# How to convert typescript npm module import syntax to ECMA2015 module import syntax

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, es6-modules, rollupjs

I'm trying to use a third party library in a Typescript project (specifically, three). As a proof-of-concept, I'm trying to resolve all of my client code as modules (without transpiling to ES5 or bundling).

my project is setup like this:

```
cgi/app.js (compiled typescript file)
node_modules/@types
node_modules/three/build/three.module.js
src/app.ts
index.html
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

And in my `index.html`

```
<head>
    <script type="module" src="node_modules/three/build/three.module.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="cgi/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

I'm trying to have typescript resolve the `three.module.js` file while also using the type declarations from `@types/three`. Normally, you would import the library with: `import { Scene } from 'three'` which gives me type support, but the compiled module doesn't have proper ES6 syntax. It needs to be `import { Scene } from './path/to/three.js`.

Unfortunately, typescript [does not support doing this automatically yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577). I can instead import the ES6 module directly (without using @types) but then I lose type support.

Post typescript compilation, is it possible to convert the module resolution from the node syntax to the ES6 syntax? (e.g. `import { Scene } from 'three'` is converted to `import { Scene } from './three.js'`?

Specifically, is it possible to leverage rollup to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Rollup's `paths` configuration value.

E.g. in my `app.ts` file I have a standard npm-style-import:

`import { somedependency } from my-dependency` (where `my-dependency` is a node module, such as `three`.)

In the `rollup.config` file, you need to tell Rollup the path to this file:

```
output: { ... },
plugins: [ ... ]
paths: {'my-dependency': './your/web/path/to/the/dependency.js'}
```

Your compiled bundle will now have a good import to that code that can be understood by the browser.